# how to connect local mysql to gae rdbms

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine

I have set up MySQL on my local computer and now I want to connect to the gae cloud database so I can use sql to load my data into gae. I got the local MySQL working using the documentation in google developers and they hint at connecting to the gae database but they don't give enough detail to do it for a new user.

I have tried many methods such as:
c:\mysql -u host:app-id.appspot.com -p

and     c:\google_sql.cmd app-id.appspot.com [guestbook]

Thankyou for your help
Dan